# trying to figure out out to turn this from a component to a function in ReactJS but i'm stuck

Tags: reactjs

I need the bottom code to work with the top. The top code was originally a component but I changed it to a function but I don't know what to do with the bottom code.

```
const listLocations = locations.map((place, id) => {
console.log(place.name)
return (
<p key={id} onClick={showLocation}>{place.name}</p>
)
})

const showLocation = (place) => {
if (this.state[place.id] === "hidden") {
this.setState(this.defaultState)
this.setState({ [place.id]: "", currentLocation: place })
} else {
this.setState({[place.id]: "hidden", currentLocation: {}})
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const listLocations = locations.map((place, id) => {
    return (
        <p key={id} onClick={() => showLocation(place)}>{place.name}</p>
    )
})

const showLocation = (place) => {
    if (this.state[place.id] === "hidden") {
        this.setState(this.defaultState)
        this.setState({ [place.id]: "", currentLocation: place })
    } else {
        this.setState({[place.id]: "hidden", currentLocation: {}})
    }
}
```

Your onClick was being passed as a lambda without any information about the place that was being clicked. I changed it to a lambda that takes that information from the context. Try it out and let us know if it works.

Remember to format/indent your code to make it more readable :)

Comment: Thank you, but I got a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" when I tried to click on anything. Is there a way I can share the entire app.js?

Comment: Would you post the full file?